# Map Layout Issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dictionary

I am new in android. I am making an app using google map.
In the layout file 3 part i.e Top Layer,Mid Layer,Bottom Layer.
In Top layer a header, in bottom Layer TAB button.
In Mid Layer Fragment and Edit text. When I click on edit box then fragment gone up. when fragment comes back at position then hte top layer is going to invisible. I don't know what happens.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/jam_alert_topbar"
     >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/midLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botLay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLay"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/descr"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLay"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:minLines="4" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/botLay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/jam_tab_n"
        android:onClick="btReport" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/map_tab_h"
        android:onClick="btMap" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/report_tab_n"
        android:onClick="btHome" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_tab_n"
        android:onClick="btSetting" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Have you tried this one?. Add windowSoftInputMode attribute in particular activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

In your xml. add android:layout_alinParentTop="true" in your top relativelayout

```
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/topLay"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/jam_alert_topbar"
android:layout_alinParentTop="true"
 >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried this android:windowSoftInputMode="ststeHidden/adjustresize"
it works but it moves all 3 layer on top and i want that athe above 2 layer are gone up

Comment: same problem Sorry :(

Comment: pleae do helful for me @Murli Ganesan

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/jam_alert_topbar">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/midLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/descr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:minLines="4" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/botLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btReport"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/jam_tab_n"
                android:onClick="btReport" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btMap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/map_tab_h"
                android:onClick="btMap" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btHome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/report_tab_n"
                android:onClick="btHome" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btSetting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/settings_tab_n"
                android:onClick="btSetting" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sir i want to make it for multiple screen not only for singla screen